# Gravitational potential $V(r)$ in a neutron star

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, potential, conventions, neutron-stars

In the Tolman-Oppenhemer-Volkhoff (TOV) equations of hydrostatic equilibirium, would the equation for gravitational potential v(r) satisfy v(0)=0 for interior of star?

If anyone has a plot of gravitational potential v(r) for the interior of neutron star, could they show that.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about the TOV equations, there is not one "gravitational" potential. The metric in the stellar interior is given by
$$(g_{\mu\nu})=\mathrm{diag}(g_{tt},g_{rr},g_{\theta\theta},g_{\phi\phi})=\mathrm{diag}(e^{\nu(r)},e^{\lambda(r)},r^2,r^2 \sin^2\theta).$$

$\nu(r)$ and $\lambda(r)$ are referred to as metric potentials. In general (meaning not in case of very special equations of state) there are no analytical expressions for $\nu(r)$ and $\lambda(r)$ inside the star. Both potentials need to be obtained by numerical integration of the TOV equations. For that it is practical to define a quantity $m(r)$ such that $$e^{\lambda(r)}\equiv\left(1-\frac{2G m(r)}{c^2 r}\right)^{-1}.$$
But for $m(r)$ there are again in general no analytical solutions.

At the stellar center however $m(r=0)=0$ holds and therefore $$e^{\lambda(0)}=1.$$
$\nu(0)$ is finite but it's value is fixed by a boundary condition at the stellar surface  so without integrating the TOV equations one can not tell what value $\nu(0)$ has.

In the Newtonian limit there is just one classical gravitational potential $$V(r)=-G\frac{m(r)}{r},$$
with the Newtonian enclosed mass $$m(r)=4\pi\int_0^r \rho(\bar r) \bar r^2 d\bar r.$$
$\rho(r)$ would be governed by the classical equation of hydrostatic equilibrium and the equation of state.
At the stellar center $m$ vanishes and $V(0)$ is indeed $0$.

This plot should give a qualitative idea about how the potentials look:
[image: Potentils]

In green the Newtonian gravitational potential $V(r)$ with it's typical $1/r$ asymptotic for $r>R_N$, in blue the general relativistic $g_{tt}(r)$ metric potential and in red the general relativistic $g_{rr}(r)$ metric potential. Outside the star all potentials can be given analytically $V(r)=-M_N/r$, $g_{tt}=-(1-2M/r)$ and $g_{rr}=(1-2M/r)^{-1}$. The Plot is in geometrized units $G=c=1$.

The interior solutions were obtained by numerical integration of the structure equations (TOV/Newtonian) for a polytropic equation of state: $$\rho(P)=m_B n_0 (\frac{p}{\kappa \rho_0})^{1/\gamma} + \frac{1}{\gamma- 1} p,$$
with $\kappa=0.05$, $\gamma=2$, $m_B=931.192\, \mathrm{MeV}$,  $\rho_0=93.119\, \mathrm{MeV}\mathrm{fm}^{-3}$,  $n_0=0.1\, \mathrm{fm}^{-3}$ and a central pressure of $P_c=150\, \mathrm{MeV}\mathrm{fm}^{-3}$. With this initial conditions the TOV equations yield a star with a gravitational mass of $M=2.228\,M_\odot$ and a radius of $R=15.9\,\mathrm{km}$. The Newtonain structure equations result in a star with gravitational mass of $M_N=6.826\,M_\odot$ and a radius of $R_N=22.5\,\mathrm{km}$. The Newtonian structure equation has less compact equilibrium configurations, since compared to the TOV equation, it lacks relativistic corrections which increase the pressure gradient.

Comment: okkk, can we not obtained some analytical expression of v(r) for constant density as given in  Springer Tracts in Modern Physics,Volume 133,Managing Editor: G. H6hler, Karlsruhe on  page 99 equation 4.27.I am enable to write the resultant equation, b/c i dont know how to use write maths in his site

Comment: Weil for constant density stars the classical potential is trivial and the TOV metric potentials are also analytic; see interior Schwarzschild solution.

Comment: There appears to be an inconsistency with your last equation and the values you give.  From the values you give, we have $m_B n_0 \equiv \rho_0$, so \begin{equation} \rho(p) = \rho_0 \Bigl( \frac{p}{\kappa \rho_0}  \Bigr)^{1/\gamma} + \frac{1}{\gamma - 1} p.\end{equation} Evaluating at $r = 0$ gives \begin{equation} \rho_0 = \rho_0 \Bigl( \frac{p_0}{\kappa \rho_0}  \Bigr)^{1/\gamma} + \frac{1}{\gamma - 1} p_0, \end{equation} With $\gamma = 2$, this equation isn't satisfied by $\kappa = 0.05$!  It is solved by $\kappa \approx 4.317$.

Comment: I am sorry the notation is a bit confusing: $\rho_0\neq\rho(P(r=0))$ that is to say $\rho_0$ is not the energy density at the center of the star. It is a constant (as you stated $m_B n_0=\rho_0$) for the approximate density of normal nuclear matter. The energy density at the center of the star with $P_c=P(r=0)=150\mathrm{MeVfm}^{-3}$ is actually $\rho(P_c)=\rho(r=0)=678.543\mathrm{MeVfm}^{-3}$.

Comment: Okay, my own resolution with *Mathematica* confirms *exactly* your radius of $R = 15.9 \, \mathrm{km}$, when I use your initial numbers.

Comment: I have two more comments:  firstly, I define the pressure and the total energy density *relative* to their central value: $\tilde{p} = p/p_c$ and $\tilde{\rho} = \rho/\rho_c$.  I also define the relativistic parameter $\alpha = p_c / \rho_c$, with the constraint $0 < \alpha \le 1$ (from the energy conditions).  Then your last equation takes the following form:\begin{equation}\tilde{\rho} = \Bigl( 1 - \frac{\alpha}{\gamma - 1} \Bigr) \tilde{p}^{1/\gamma} + \frac{\alpha \tilde{p}}{\gamma - 1}.\end{equation} (such that $\tilde{\rho}(0) \equiv 1$ at central pressure $\tilde{p}(0) \equiv 1$).

Comment: Second comment:  How can we trust your last equation, for high pressure states?  I asked a question about this here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775348/what-is-the-equation-of-state-eos-of-a-polytrope-in-general-relativity#775348