# Is total energy density in energy-momentum tensor equal to total energy density with relativistic mass density?

Tags: general-relativity, astrophysics, density, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, neutron-stars

I am studying the Tolman-Oppenheimer-Volkhoff (TOV) equations of hydrostatic equilibirium:
     $$\frac{dP}{dr}= −(G/c^2)(\epsilon + P)\frac{M + \frac{4\pi(r^3)P}{c^2}}{r^2− \frac{2GMr}{c^2}} \tag{1}$$
I want to choose a total central energy density $\epsilon$ and I am confused about two possible formulations
$$\epsilon=\rho c^2 \tag{2}$$ 
and
$$\epsilon= (1+a)\rho + k*{\rho^{\Gamma}/\Gamma} − 1 \tag{3}$$
Can anyone tell me in what case which equation is best for chosen energy density in solving equation (1) and also clarify, me whether the $\rho$ in equations (2) and (3) are relativistic energy densities or rest mass density?
I choose $\rho({\rm central})=5.3452·10^{14}$ g/cc but not deciding how to take $\epsilon$.

Comment: I tried to shorten and improve the title, math formatting and spelling. You should check and correct the result and also give a unit to the $\rho$ value in the last sentence

Comment: umar, I edited @freecharly's LaTeX rather heavily, so you might want to check my work. In particular I have used `\tag{}` to set equation numbers, marked up the Greek letters you wrote in unicode for a more uniform appearance, and made use of `\frac{}{}`  to set fractions.

Comment: In your version of the TOV equation $\epsilon$ is the total energy density, which is $>\rho c^2$ since it also includes a kinetic component.

Answer (score 1):

Eq. (3) of OP seems to be polytropic EoS in which $\rho$ seems to be a rest mass density. Eq. (2) in this context wrong when $\epsilon$ is supposed to be the (internal) energy density or the $T_0{}^0$ component of the energy-momentum tensor of an ideal fluid.

Let me stress that the entire equation of state (EoS) and (internal) energy density vs. rest mass density "business" has nothing to do with "$E=m c^2$". Not saying anything about relativity: the internal energy density is in general not equal to the rest mass density; that is just thermodynamics. Maybe a personal remark: Einstein's "$E=m c^2$" is way to popular and a brutal understatement of the man's genius. When looking at it in geometrical units this relation is a triviality. $E^2=m^2 c^4 +p^2 c^2$ tells a story and has physical meaning but I am getting carried away.

The TOV eq. have to thermodynamic quantities in them: Pressure and (internal) energy density: no rest mast density or number density or anything. The eq. (1) of OP, my eq. (4) and an EoS in the form $\epsilon(P)$ form a complete and solvable system.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d M}{d r}=4\pi\, \frac{\epsilon(P(r))}{c^2}\, r^2\tag{4}
\end{equation}

I dislike the form of eq. (3) because it lacks proper definitions of the involved quantities and the pressure coefficient $k$ is not defined dimensionless apart from this it looks to miss some factors of $c$. And I have no idea what $a$ is supposed to be. If one assumes a polytropic EoS 
\begin{equation}
P\equiv \kappa \epsilon_0 \left(\frac{n}{n_0}\right)^\gamma,\tag{5}
\end{equation}
then the first law of thermodynamic (at zero temperature)
\begin{equation}
\epsilon=\frac{d U}{d V}=-P+\mu\frac{dN}{dV}=-P+\mu n = -P + \left(\frac{d\epsilon}{d n}\right)n\tag{6}
\end{equation} dictates

\begin{equation}
\epsilon=m_B c^2 n + \frac{\kappa \epsilon_0}{\gamma-1}\left(\frac{n}{n_0}\right)^\gamma \tag{7}
\end{equation}
as a solution of the differential equation (6).
Where $P$ is pressure, $\epsilon$ is energy density $\mu$ is chemical potential $\mu=d\epsilon / d n$ and $n$ is number density. The constants related to the EoS are particle rest mass $m_B$, an arbitrary number density $n_0$ an arbitrary energy density $\epsilon_0$ a dimensionless pressure coefficient $\kappa$ and a relativistic polytropic index $\gamma$. I only introduced $n_0$ and $\epsilon_0$ so that $\kappa$ is dimensionless and independent of $\gamma$; if you do not do it this way, then $\kappa$ becomes dependent of $\gamma$, like $k$ of OP is dependent of $\Gamma$ just to ensure dimensional homogeneity.

$\epsilon$ has a rest mas contribution $m_B c^2 n=\rho c^2$ but also a pressure term. This is a consequence of the ansatz (5) and the classical first law of thermodynamics.

One can combine eq. (5) and (7) to 
\begin{equation}
\epsilon=\frac{m_B c^2}{n_0}\left(\frac{P}{\kappa \epsilon_0}\right)^{1/\gamma}+\frac{P}{\gamma-1}, \tag{8}
\end{equation}
which is an EoS of the form $\epsilon(P)$  which can be used in the TOV eqs. I gave some working numbers for this kind of polytrope in my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296297

Eq. (3) of OP without a relation to the pressure is not enough to solve the TOV eqs. If one wants to integrate the TOV eqs. one has to choose the EoS, for the polytrope I presented meaning choosing $\kappa$, $\gamma$, $n_0$ and $\epsilon_0$, and a central pressure. IF you want some specific central energy density or number density (which can be related to rest mass density $n=\rho/m_B$) you could use eq. (4) to find the corresponding pressure, granted you choose some polytropic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use Eq. (2) as the energy density is the $T^0_0$ component of the stress energy tensor. You may need sometimes to be careful whether the 00 components are one up and one down, or both contravariant or covariant.

In TOV it is $\rho c^2$, as you can see in the relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation).

In GR it is much easier to work with rest masses, rest matter densities and rest energy densities; except for radiation where we put in its energy density since there is no rest mass. The relativistic factors get complicated when it depends on coordinates, so we let the dependence come from the metric (which is why you have to be careful with which indices it refers to)

Comment: I have to work with equ(3) is there any idea how to use equ 3 and the constant "a" in it is troubling how to find its value

Comment: I have no idea where that came from